# Maven. How to inherit profile from paren pom.xml?

Tags: java, maven

I have 2 profiles in my parent `pom.xml` (for production and for development). So I want to inherit this profiles in my child modules... How I can achieve this? How I can inherit parent's profile? Or I need to specify profile with same ID in child module and all be ok?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to give the following into your child pom.xml file to inherit from your parent which implies to inherit all profiles you have defined in your parent:

```
   <project ..>
      <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

      <parent>
        <groupId>TheGroupIdYourParentHas</groupId>
        <artifactId>TheArtifactIdYourParentHas</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
      </parent>
      ...
   </project>
```

BTW. You should think about using profiles for [distinguishing between production and development](http://java.dzone.com/articles/maven-profile-best-practices). Usually you should simply call

```
mvn package
```

to produce the right package which is for production without using of any profile. I wrote an [blog article to handle such things in a better way](http://blog.soebes.de/index.php?/archives/340-Maven-Configuration-For-Multipe-Environments.html).

Comment: hm. thanks for link, will read. But you don't fully understand the question: I have `<parent>` section in child module..I want to have 2 `<profiles>` section - in parent's `pom.xml` and in child's `pom.xml`. But I want to have only 2 profile at all. So all what I need is to specify in child module `<profile>` section with _same_ ID?]

Comment: I'm not sure if defining the profile in the child with the same id will do what you expect. What you can do is to overwrite the configuration of plugins via **combine.self="override"** [see pom.xml reference](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html).

Comment: My question in other words: I want to have 2 profiles sections - in parent pom.xml and in child pom.xml.  And I want to execute both profile sections during packaging. i.e. I want to package my app using `mvn package -P development` ( so both profiles will be activated (child profile and parent profile)). How to achieve this? Bound both profiles to same ID ('development')?

Comment: Ah..ok. That makes it more clear. I would suggest to have two profiles one in parent one in child with different id's which can be activated by **mvn -Pprofile-parent,profile-child** which will activate both of them. Using the same id as i wrote i'm not sure if this will work as you expect.

Comment: It's works, thanks :). And about your advice about distinguishing profiles: it's better to  keep only one profile - 'development' and kick-out 'production' profile? So instead running 'production' profile I will simply run `package` goal to get application build ready for production?

Comment: The default should be to build without profile which is usually the production result. Yeah that's best. Define exception via profiles but the usual use case.